# Is there a way to prevent Outlook from asking about whether or not to save changes after opening it with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following Excel 2016 VBA code does open Outlook:

```
Sub mail()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objMail
       .To = "Yourname@Yourdomain.com"
       .Subject = "My Subject"
       .Body = "My message." 
       .Display        'This creates and opens the Email. The user has to manually click the send button in Outlook afterwards
    End With

End Sub
```

Now, the user has the valid option to immediately close Outlook.
However in this case, Outlook opens a pop-up window about whether or not to save changes.

Is there a way to prevent Outlook from opening this pop-up alert window by some Excel VBA code?

Comment: Is asking to save the changes from the new created e-mail you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use `oldiscard`

```
Sub mail()
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

With objMail
   .To = "Yourname@Yourdomain.com"
   .Subject = "My Subject"
   .Body = "My message."
   .Display        'This creates and opens the Email. The user has to manually click the send button in Outlook afterwards
End With

If Msg("Do you rwant to close this mail?" & vbCrLf, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then objMail.Close oldiscard
End Sub
```

This code will ask you if you want to close your email, if yes it will close without asking you if you want to save change. 
A good workaround would be to put `oldiscard` once you trigger the outlook button close, for it you will have to use `Inspector`.

You might have to follow this tutorial and adapt it : [See the tutorial here](https://office-watch.com/2015/code-close-all-open-outlook-email-messages-without-saving/)